# How can I tell if a clutser-randomised crossover trial has made a unit of analysis error?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, clinical-trials, clustered-standard-errors, sandwich

I am studying the following paper:

https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jama/fullarticle/2698491

This is a cluster randomised control trial with crossover. I want to ensure they have not made a unit of analysis error which may inflate their effect size and artifically reduce their p value. I don't feel confident to judge this without asking for help.

In case it is relevant to the statistics, the crossover in this trial does not mean each patient gets both the intervention and control, but rather the custer unit (the EMS agency) switches from offering the intervention offering the control (or vice versa) and the patient population in each crossover period is made of different patients (though hopefully similar as they are under the same cluster unit).

The authors state:
"To quantify the treatment effect, we used generalized estimating equations (GEEs) with an identity link and robust standard errors, accounting for randomization cluster and number of interim analyses"

They then later state:
"We used 2-sided tests with an α of .05 as the threshold for statistical significance."

I appreciate that they seem to have accounted for clustering with the use of robust standard errors and their use of the Huber-White estimator (mentioned in their protocol), but I wanted to be sure that their comment on a 2-sided test (the same as a 2-tail test?) doesn't suggest that they have assessed the outcome on an individual level without accounting for clustering.

I think the data they report in Table 2 suggests that they have assessed the difference on an individual level for the primary outcome because they just report a difference effect between intervention and control.

I am a paramedic, not a statistician, so I would really appreciate some help in working this out. If the answer is that we cannot know because they do not describe the issue in enough detail, then that is also useful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The 'two-sided' test indeed means they consider deviations of the test statistic in both the negative and positive sense (lower and upper tail). A two-sided $\alpha=0.05$ is very standard, if you were interested in only one direction (e.g. we only want to see if LT is superior to ETI) you would then have to do that test at one-sided $\alpha=0.025$. If you were to use a one-sided $\alpha=0.05$ you'd be working at twice the type I error rate.

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'outcome on an individual level', the whole goal of such models is to provide an average (difference in) probability of survival. They did not provide any details on how this was parametrized, e.g. is it $n$ patients with a yes/no outcome each or is it a site that has $k/n$ survivors - mathematically these are the same but the former is more flexible in terms of model specification. The GEE's robust standard errors correct for the fact that observations from one cluster are not expected to be independent, which is otherwise an assumption in most statistical models. Removing correlations between within-cluster observations makes the results more generalizable, for example to agencies that weren't in this particular study, and in fact *not* doing so (by treating patients in one cluster as independent whereas they are not) would lead to bias.

Obviously any given individual may have a much higher or much lower probability of survival, and there might even be some for whom the intervention is *worse* instead of better, but **on average** they show that LT increases survival probability at 72h by ~3%. A problem with GEE is that it only provides so-called marginal (population-level) estimates. Someone treating a patient might very well be interested if LT is really better for *this* patient, all the results tell you right now is that if you were to give everyone within the population/protocol under study LT instead of ETI you expect to end up with ~3% higher survival at 72h.  *(edit)*: and, not unimportantly, that this difference is unlikely to have manifested due to random variability in the outcome being studied.

Comment: Note that in a cluster randomized trial the _unit of analysis_ is still the individual patient.  But the effective sample size used in computing standard errors, P-values, and confidence limits is between the number of clusters and the number of patients, usually being closer to the number of clusters.  Also, GEE approaches are not quite as accurate as using a full likelihood model, e.g., a Bayesian or frequentist random effects model, with random intercepts for clusters.

Comment: Thank you both. This was very helpful. Thanks for taking the time to read the paper also.